# Writing in a file with Phonegap

Tags: file, cordova

I've a problem with the Phonegap File API.
Here a simple example of my problem :

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {

        for(var i=0;i<300;i++){
            alert(i);
            writer.write(i);
        }

}
```

Navigator alert 0.
0 is written is the file
Navigator alert 1.
And nothing else.

Thanks

Comment: Read your question few times but still don't understand it :(

Comment: Can you rephrase that last sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap file operations are async. What is most probably happening is that the first write has not finished before you call the second write which would cause an exception, a PendingOperation one IIRC. You will either want to build up a string with all the information you want to write to the file and send it over in one write command or you'll need to wait for the onwriteend event from the FileWriter before you can write the next item.

Take a look at the FileWriter full example for an idea of how to use onwriteend.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter